# How to dynamically switch to another kernel in FreeBSD?

Tags: kernel, freebsd

I know that Linux has 'kexec' to do that. How to do this in FreeBSD? It's quite important for system administrators.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FreeBSD doesn't support this operation at the moment. There was a discussion about it on the hackers@freebsd.org mailing list last year, starting [here](http://lists.freebsd.org/pipermail/freebsd-hackers/2011-June/035628.html). It looks as though it's a long way off, due to some fairly fundamental differences between the Linux and FreeBSD boot procedures and kernel architectures.